# getting double msg in NODE-Red

Tags: node-red

Sometimes I get two msg from one flow, and I have no idea why...
They have same msg.id and time, and shows both when debugging and for example when saving data I get double of everything. 
The one I have now is pretty stright, a manual trigger->http request->function

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: You are going to have to give us a LOT more to work with here. Edit the question to include details about version (e.g. nodejs, node-red) and probable and exported version of your flow.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thouht it was a "common" problem since I get it alot no matter what flow.... I'll check later and try to post more info.

Comment: Helps to dubbelcheck, found some old lines that I had forgot to comment out.
Had both node.send(msg) and return msg;  ..stupid misstake.